Best way to cache css , js and fonts cache for glassfish webserver
I have Glassfish webserver and I want My application cache the files in client side , I try multiple way And it does not work for any method and some method use apache webserver that is not in my case , basically I have this in my html file(Yes html file):

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wait Application Load</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../theme/management/loader.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../js/loader.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/datepicker/persian-datepicker.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/datatables/datatables.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../theme/management/base.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../plugins/jquery/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../plugins/datepicker/persian-date.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../plugins/datepicker/persian-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../theme/management/control.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../js/management.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript"
            src="../plugins/tiny/tinymce.min.js"
    ></script>
</head>

All of this load after reload page and total of resources file is 5.9mb that huge for any time I create request! so I want cache this in client side, I try this :
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=31536000, public">

not work for me , maybe can create question why html file I use not jsf or servlet or jsp! Thats because I create my own engine site that faster to develop and build.
So In glassfish-web.xml or web.xml how can I create cache role?
I check multiple site and found the old version that is not work.
here my basic glassfish-web.xml and web.xml :
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD
GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN"
        "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>

web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
         version="6.0">
    <error-page>
        <location>/Application/Page/Error</location>
    </error-page>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML files</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML files</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

I use this link and its not valid anymore :Caching Example
GlassFish Version : 7.0.14

I don't know why Html can't Control the cache, by the way for resolve the cache file with servlet filter :
@WebFilter("/*")
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                long lastModified = file.lastModified();
                long now = new Date().getTime();
                long expirationTime = now + 86400000; // 24 hours
                HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                httpResponse.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", lastModified);
                httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", expirationTime);
                httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=86400");
//OTHER STUFF
}
//...
}

The important note is that if you need to add response header , you can not added after response content!(It's Stream)

How about caching using the .htaccess file. Something like this may work:
# BEGIN Expire headers  
<IfModule mod_expires.c>  
  # Turn on the module.
  ExpiresActive on
  # Set the default expiry times.
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>  


check the question , Its not apache web server that work under .htaccess file.
